# Excel VBA Runtime 1004

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, runtime-error

For some reason, I am receiving a

> runtime error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error)

while I am trying to insert a formula. The file/ worksheet is active, the worksheet is not protected. The rowcount picks up the correct number of rows. So I am at a loss here.

```
'Adjust date format in temporary column
RowCount = Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To RowCount
    Worksheets("Data").Range("O" & i).Formula = "=TEXT(H" & i & "),""yyyy-mm-dd"")"
Next
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The additional ") was the trick...

```
'Adjust date format in temporary column
RowCount = Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To RowCount
    Worksheets("Data").Range("O" & i).Formula = "=TEXT(H" & i & ",""yyyy-mm-dd"")"
Next
```

works just fine.